# Is there a way to change which shares are shown on the bottom of the iOS 5 notifications screen?

Tags: ios, notifications

The bottom of the iOS 5 notifications screen show the Shares for some enterprises (Apple, Google, Yahoo!). Is there a way to configure which one I want to see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shares shown are the one you set up in the **Stocks** app.

- Open *Stocks
- Tap the *i* on the bottom right corner
- Delete or add new shares

Those will be the ones shown in the notifications screen.